# What is the cross-sectional area of solid, 14 AWG THHN wire?

Tags: electrical, conduit

I have found that **stranded** 14 AWG THHN is [6.258 sq mm](https://cdn.automationdirect.com/static/specs/wirethhn.pdf), but I am having a hard time finding the value for **solid** 14 AWG THHN.  I keep seeing [2.08 sq mm](https://www.noisebridge.net/wiki/American_wire_gauge), but I find it hard to believe that the cross-sectional area of *stranded* THHN is ~3 times larger than *solid* THHN.

BTW, I am using these figures to calculate maximum conduit fill as allowed by the NEC specs.  If you are interested, I have created a [conduit fill calculator](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14e80j-Z7yy3Z9qhGbqdi6FftahU63paLkB_l58dljjo/edit#gid=492192588) using Google Sheets.  You are more than welcome to use it.  Just make a copy of the spreadsheet first.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Be aware that in home construction, the physical limits of something is often less important than what code allows, and I'm pretty sure that's true here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @DanielGriscom!  That's exactly what I am trying to do - calculate what the NEC code allows.

Comment: Keep in mind that googling .conduit fil calculator" will bring up dozens of reasonably well-executed calcs of considerable complexity. *No need to reinvent the wheel*  My only gripe with them is you cannot for instance, select 10/3 UF cable, which is treated as a round wire of the large dimension.

Comment: I tried googling for conduit fill calculators, but I didn't like any of them for two reasons: 1) they didn't factor in the number of bends, and 2) didn't include how the calculations were being done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEC Chapter 9, Table 8 shows 2.08 mm² is the CSA of bare solid #14 awg, and stranded is 2.68 mm².

But those numbers are just the CSA of the copper. You need to use the CSA including insulation, which varies with type of insulation. Those are found in Chapter 9, Table 5, in which you find #14 varies from 3.548 to 18.90 mm².

Comment: Thanks, @NoSparksPlease.  That got me on the right track!  In the 2017 edition, Ch 9, note (10), pg 70 –679 states the following.  To save the brain damage, I am just going to roll with the **worst-case** CSA.
_The values for approx. conductor diameter & area shown in Table 5 are based on **worst-case** scenario & indicate round concentric-lay-**stranded** conductors.
**Solid** & round concentric-lay-**stranded** conductor values are grouped together for the purpose of Table 5..._

Answer (score 1):

2.08 mm^2 is for the **conductor**, and is relevant to geeky physics considerations like determining scrap value or computing wire resistance the hard way.  You won't do much with this figure, as all the math is already done for you in 310.15 and 240.4.

6.258 mm^2 is for the **wire, inclusive of insulation**, and is relevant to practical questions of conduit fill.   As an electrician you are far more likely to work with this figure.

Comment: Maybe a typo 420.4?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease quite right, thanks.